# Connection to postgresql hangs over SSH tunnel on OSX

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, postgresql, ssh-tunnel

Trying to connect to a remote PG server on OSX but it keeps timing out.

First, I set up the tunnel:

```
ssh -L 5433:serverip:5432 user@serverip
```

Then in a separate terminal I attempt to connect to PG:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U user
```

Here the connection just sits for about 3 minutes. Then I get the following message:

```
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
```

On the ssh tunnel terminal, all I see is this:

```
channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
(3 mins later:)channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
```

I've tried every variation I can think of (localhost vs 127.0.0.1, diff usernames). Nothing is working. This exact setup works fine on Windows Putty, so its not the server. I am also able to ssh and run psql on the server, so it's not PG.

Comment: The error message clearly indicates a connectivity problem between ssh server and postgres server. Yet it seems you are running both on the same host. Are you sure you are specifying the same IP in both locations in that `ssh` command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you have `postgresql` configured to listen only on loopbavk (`localhost`). You should use the forwarding like this:

```
ssh -L 5433:localhost:5432 user@serverip
```

Otherwise it will try to connect to public IP of your server, where is nothing listening or nothing authorized to login.

Comment: you are welcome. Glad to help.

Comment: This answer cannot explain the symptoms described in the question. I already tested the scenario described in this answer, and it does not trigger a timeout. Rather it cause the connection to fail instantly with `open failed: connect failed: Connection refused`.

Comment: It depends on your configuration. Basically, you might have `ExitOnForwardFailure` option, which would cause your behaviour or not and it is silently ignored, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a very similar issue (Ubuntu here): ssh tunnel for PostgreSQL's port, psql acessing remote database using that tunnel. When I requested an autocomplete on psql (select * from x), the tunnel would hang/crash.

Solution: change the MTU for all interfaces from 1500 to 576. 
Explanation: http://www.snailbook.com/faq/mtu-mismatch.auto.html

There went a few hours of my life..

Comment: That is terrible advice.